# mvc required by dropdownlistfor selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

MVC 4 I have the option to put two email addresses at list one is compulsory 
and a dropdownlist preferred email work/Alternative
on submit I want to validate the selected value of the dropdownlistfor and by the selected value to make the Work email address or Alternative email address field required 
How do I do that ? is it possible to do that with a custom validation?

Model:

```
    public string WorkEmail { get; set; }
    public string AlternativeEmail { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PreferredEmails { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution

```
 public class WorkModel
    {
        [CorrectMail]
        public string WorkEmail { get; set; }
        [CorrectMail]
        public string AlternativeEmail { get; set; }
        public string PreferredEmail { get; set; }
    }

    public class CorrectMail : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var model = validationContext.ObjectInstance as WorkModel;
            if (model == null) return new ValidationResult("Model is empty");

            if (model.PreferredEmail == "WorkEmail" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.WorkEmail))
            {
                return new ValidationResult("You have selected work email but did not fill it");
            }
            if (model.PreferredEmail == "AlternativeEmail" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AlternativeEmail))
            {
                return new ValidationResult("You have selected alternative email but did not fill it");
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do a custom validation routine. My preferred way of doing it is by  [Validating in the Service Layer](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs)